# Django model field __class__ shows itself as different class?

Tags: python, django

This is the avatar model field I am using:

```
class AvatarField(models.ImageField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.width = kwargs.pop('width', config.width)
        self.height = kwargs.pop('height', config.height)

        kwargs['upload_to'] = kwargs.get('upload_to', config.upload_to)

        super(AvatarField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': forms.AvatarField}
        defaults['width'] = self.width
        defaults['height'] = self.height
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(AvatarField, self).formfield(**defaults)

    def save_form_data(self, instance, data):
        # if data and self.width and self.height:
        file_ = data['file']
        if file_:

            image = Image.open(StringIO(file_.read()))
            image = image.crop(data['box'])
            image = image.resize((self.width, self.height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

            content = StringIO()
            image.save(content, config.save_format, quality=config.save_quality)

            file_name = '{}.{}'.format(os.path.splitext(file_.name)[0], config.save_format)

            # new_data = SimpleUploadedFile(file.name, content.getvalue(), content_type='image/' + config.save_format)
            new_data = InMemoryUploadedFile(content, None, file_name, 'image/' + config.save_format, len(content.getvalue()), None)
            super(AvatarField, self).save_form_data(instance, new_data)
```

It's being used in Profile model:

```
avatar = AvatarField(upload_to='avatars', width=100, height=100)
```

But `__class__` shows as ImageFieldFile??

```
In [1]: p = Profile.objects.all()[0]

In [2]: p.avatar.__class__
Out[2]: django.db.models.fields.files.ImageFieldFile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some more [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field) I realised this:

> It’s important to realize that a Django field class is not what is
>   stored in your model attributes. The model attributes contain normal
>   Python objects. The field classes you define in a model are actually
>   stored in the Meta class when the model class is created (the precise
>   details of how this is done are unimportant here). This is because the
>   field classes aren’t necessary when you’re just creating and modifying
>   attributes. Instead, they provide the machinery for converting between
>   the attribute value and what is stored in the database or sent to the
>   serializer.